# Can't add \raisebox to ToC in XeTeX

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex

In XeLaTeX I've defined the following command:

```
\newcommand*{\PoETeX}{P\kern -.15em\raisebox{-0.21em}{O}\kern -.05em E\TeX}
```

as a simple (non-robust) way to create a silly logo styled after `\LaTeX`.

It works fine until I try to insert it into the table of contents with something like:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\PoETeX}
```

at which point I get the following from `xelatex`:

> ! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.  
>                   \par  l.11  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\PoETeX}

The problem seems to be caused by`\raisebox` — taking out raisebox, or using `\addcontentsline*` gets rid of the error.

A minimal example can be found below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newcommand*{\PoETeX}{P\kern -.15em\raisebox{-0.21em}{O}\kern -.05em E\TeX}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\PoETeX}
\section*{\PoETeX}

\begin{verse}

There once was a poem called \PoETeX\\
That's name sounded somewhat /pəˈθɛtɛk/.\\
\hspace*{2em}It was really quite sad,\\
\hspace*{2em}to see pronunciation so bad,\\
And to read such a terrible /ˈlɪme(ə)rɛk/!

\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you plan to often use `\PoETeX` in moving arguments, it's better to use

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\PoETeX}{%
  P\kern -.15em\raisebox{-0.21em}{O}\kern -.05em E\TeX}
```

so you won't have to put `\protect` before the command in many places.

Roughly speaking, defining a command with `\DeclareRobustCommand` is like having `\protect` before it whenever it's needed. Don't take the habit of defining *all* commands like this: use the technique only where it proves necessary.

---

Alternative definition:

```
\protected\def\PoETeX{%
  P\kern -.15em\raisebox{-0.21em}{O}\kern -.05em E\TeX}
```

This is actually more efficient than `\DeclareRobustCommand`, but has the disadvantage of using low level commands.

Comment: Yah, I'd rather not use any TeX commands like `\def`. `\PoETeX` is actually being passed in as an argument to an environment which is then creating the ToC entry in my actual document. What's the standard practice; should I always create robust commands if I want to pass in a command for the argument, or should I do something like `\protect #2` in the package where it inserts the ToC entry? (Should I check for robustness as the package maintainer, or should the user define robust commands if they want to pass then to my environment?)

Comment: @SamWhited If you don't have precise control on what is passed to `\addcontentsline`, then it's better to use `\DeclareRobustCommand` for commands whose expansion is fragile (for instance it contains `\raisebox`); however, most commands are robust, so this matters only in a few cases, probably. Using `\protect#2` would not help, because `\protect` acts only on *one* token, so if `#2` is `Here's \PoETex` the trick wouldn't work.

Comment: Sounds good; I'll leave it up to the users to make sure their commands are robust (As you said, it's kind of an edge case anyways and not likely to happen often in practice).

Comment: Another quick usage question (though this might deserve its own full tex.se question). If the `\PoETeX` command is defined in a file like the one I posted (but without the document preamble, etc.), and `\input`-ed into another file which contains the ToC how can I get it to stop complaining that `\PoETeX` is undefined on the second build (when the ToC is included in the doc)?

Comment: @SamWhited You must ensure that commands are defined before using them. *Never* define a command in a file that's `\input` after `\documentclass` if it appears in section titles or captions. There's no way to make it defined when the table of contents is typeset, if `\input` is after `\tableofcontents`. Oh, well, one *may* record the definition in the `.aux` file, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Ah, oh well; I kinda figured that would be the answer, but I was hoping I was wrong. Thanks anyhow

Comment: Shouldn't the `\raisebox` use `ex`?

Comment: @azetina I used the same setting as the OP.

Answer (score 8):

You need to protect the fragile command `\PoETeX`:

```
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\PoETeX}
```

Comment: Oh, right... moving argument and all that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SamWhited exactly.